# getForegroundColor() for all the text in a Slides presentation returns empty

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-slides

I am trying to get the color of all the text in a slides presentation. I have:

```
 var slides = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides();

 var pageElements = slides.reduce(function (list, slide) {
    return list.concat(slide.getPageElements());
  }, []);

  var textRanges = pageElements.reduce(function (list, pageElement) {
    if (pageElement.getPageElementType() == "SHAPE") {
      for (var i=0; i < pageElement.asShape().getText().getRuns().length; i++){
        ui.alert(pageElement.asShape().getText().getRuns()[i].getTextStyle().getForegroundColor());
      }
    }
    return list;
  }, []);
```

But the colors seem to be empty/blank even though I've set the colors in my presentation to red, purple, yellow, etc. I've also tried appending "asRgbColor()" and that doesn't alert me anything. How do I get the text color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the text colors in Google Slides.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modification points:

- In order to retrieve the color as string using `asRgbColor()`, how about using `asHexString()`?

  - Or if you want to retrieve the red, green and blue as the integer number, you can also use `getRed()`, `getGreen()` and `getBlue()`.
- In this case, RGB color is retrieved.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please modify as follows.

From:

```
var textRanges = pageElements.reduce(function (list, pageElement) {
  if (pageElement.getPageElementType() == "SHAPE") {
    for (var i=0; i < pageElement.asShape().getText().getRuns().length; i++){
      ui.alert(pageElement.asShape().getText().getRuns()[i].getTextStyle().getForegroundColor());
    }
  }
  return list;
}, []);
```

To:

```
var textRanges = pageElements.reduce(function (list, pageElement) {
  if (pageElement.getPageElementType() == "SHAPE") {
    var text = pageElement.asShape().getText().getRuns(); // Added
    for (var i=0; i < text.length; i++){ // Modified
      if (text[i].getTextStyle().getForegroundColor().getColorType() == SlidesApp.ColorType.RGB) { // Added
        list.push({text: text[i].asString(), color: text[i].getTextStyle().getForegroundColor().asRgbColor().asHexString()}); // Modified
      }
    }
  }
  return list;
}, []);
```

- In this case, you can retrieve the result by `textRanges`. The result includes the object like `{"text":"sample","color":"#000000"}`.

#### References:

- [getRuns](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-range#getRuns())
- [asString()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-range#asString())
- [getForegroundColor()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/text-style#getForegroundColor())
- [Class Color](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/color)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: @Tedinoz Thank you for editing it. I had not noticed about it. Thank you.